# Updating a table in MS_Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a few databases and I need to insert a string value in front of some of the values. I have the following code:

```
UPDATE DB_AlarmTest SET DB_AlarmTest.Address = "DB40," & [Address]
WHERE DB_AlarmTest.Address 
NOT LIKE '%DB40%';
```

I dont want my adresses to come out like this: "DB40,DB40,DB40,2.0" If i execute the query more than once, so I added the " NOT LIKE '%DB40%' " part

Can someone tell my why this is not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what exactly isn't working? what does it do wrong?

Comment: Well, thats where it becomes spooky!

When I enter the code as following:

UPDATE DB_AlarmTest SET DB_AlarmTest.Address = "DB40," &[Address]
WHERE DB_AlarmTest.Address NOT LIKE '%DB40%';

(the WHERE and NOT LIKE on 1 line)

The code just returns my Address column without any changes.

When I enter it as this:

UPDATE DB_AlarmTest SET DB_AlarmTest.Address = "DB40," & [Address]
WHERE DB_AlarmTest.Address 
NOT LIKE '%DB40%';

(The WHERE and NOT LIKE seperated on 2 lines)

The code keeps adding "DB40," every time I execute the query

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the usual ANSI options in MS Access, the wildcard is *, not %, so:

```
UPDATE DB_AlarmTest 
SET DB_AlarmTest.Address = "DB40," & [Address]
WHERE DB_AlarmTest.Address Not Like "*DB40*"
```